# Can I search for, or be notified of, bumped questions?

Tags: support

Is that possible, or do I just have to eyeball questions for "bumped to the homepage"?

Comment: That's rather a question for the main Meta, as it's not specific to ours. Over there, related: [Is there any way I can see if a questions has been bumped by Community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291413/192154), plus [others on that topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bumped+by+community+is%3Aq).

Comment: Please post that as an answer, Izzy. Thanks (or should I just delete this?)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it should be migrated – and my comments are not really answering the question (verbatim) but just "pointing over there" to related topics. Though the first link answers your "search for", I don't want to duplicate that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, bumping to the homepage is kinda the entire point of this, so normally you wouldn't search for these specifically - you'd just see questions pop up on the homepage periodically.

That said, it *is* possible to audit these via the public data: [here's an example of a query that'll return the 500 questions bumped most recently](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/631713/recently-bumped-questions).

#### See also: [Is there any way to see which posts Community has bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/is-there-any-way-to-see-which-posts-community-has-bumped)